# How can I find the difference in two rows and divide this result by the sum of two rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I find the difference in two rows and divide this result by the sum of two rows?

Here is how to do it in Excel.

[image]

Here is the formula I want to replicate, using Python.

```
=ABS(((B3-B2)/(B3+B2)/2)/((A3-A2)/(A3+A2)/2))
```

I know the difference can be calculated with `df.diff()`, but I can't figure out how to do the sum.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Price':[50,46],'Quantity':[3,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `rolling.sum` with a window size of 2:

```
(df.diff()/df.rolling(2).sum()).eval('abs(Quantity/Price)')
0    NaN
1    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you already have the `diff` then already you have two row `sum`

> Since `diff` :  `x[2]-x[1] Then 'sum' : x[2]+x[1]=x[2]*2-(x[2]-x[1])`

In your case the sum can be calculated by

```
df*2-df.diff()
Out[714]: 
   Price  Quantity
0    NaN       NaN
1   96.0       9.0
```

So the output is

```
(df.diff()/(df*2-df.diff())).eval('abs(Quantity/Price)')
Out[718]: 
0    NaN
1    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

For small dataframes the use of `.eval()` is not efficient.

The following is faster upto some `100.000` rows:

`df = (df.diff() / df.rolling(2).sum()).div(2)
df['result'] = abs(df.Quantity / df.Price)`

`32.9 ms ± 1.05 ms` per loop `(mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`
vs.
`39.6 ms ± 931 µs` per loop `(mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`